# Origen de 'esquirol'

Tags: etimología, catalán

Espero que ésta pregunta sea suficientemente interesante para sobrevivir aquí aunque su sitio adecuado sería el inexistente StackExchange de uso del Catalán...

Quien acepta trabajar en una empresa donde los obreros mantienen una huelga es llamado un `esquirol`. Su uso es peyorativo; la palabra viene del Catalan, idioma en que quiere decir `ardilla` y seguramente entro en uso al inicio del Siglo XX.

Ahora bien, no veo nada particularmente despreciable en una ardilla que justifique este uso. Pero el otro dia tuve una idea. ¿Será posible que se adoptara la palabra `esquirol` simplemente porque rima con `overol`? Es una teoría bonita, pero agradeceré tanto si es confirmada como si es refutada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta la tienes en la [wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquirol):

> Esquirol es una palabra catalana que significa 'ardilla'. Es también el sobrenombre de la localidad barcelonesa de Santa María de Corcó, es decir L´Esquirol, de donde procedería, según la versión de diversas fuentes respaldadas por el artículo correspondiente a la voz de la edición digital del Diccionario de la Real Academia Española, un numeroso contingente de obreros que, a finales del siglo XIX, ocupó el puesto de trabajo de los de Manlleu durante una huelga.
>
> Ésta es también la versión del industrial manlleuense Rafael Puget, quien en sus memorias, reproducidas por Josep Pla en Un senyor de Barcelona (1945), remite el hecho a una de las primeras huelgas de Cataluña.
>
> Otras versiones sostienen, sin embargo, que el uso apodístico de esquirol es más antiguo, hunde sus raíces en el proceso de formación del más embrionario asociacionismo obrerista catalán y precede, incluso, a la figuración de la huelga como instrumento de lucha del mismo.
>
> Esta versión está respaldada por documentos periodísticos que probarían que, ya en 1841, en la localidad barcelonesa de Igualada y en el contexto de los conflictos suscitados por la implantación de la Sociedad de Protección Mutua de Tejedores de Barcelona,3 se aplicaba el apodo esquirol a los tejedores no asociados, frente a los asociados apodados moros.
>
> Se considera también esquirol a quien trabaja para poner en funcionamiento los servicios mínimos prescritos por la ley en algunos países. Esta persona actúa de acuerdo con lo acordado por la autoridad laboral gubernativa y los patronos, ya que casi nunca patronos y sindicatos convocantes de las huelgas acuerdan servicios mínimos con los que estén de acuerdo las dos partes. En los últimos años se le está llamado esquirol a aquellos que se esconden en el momento de reclamar algo y luego se benefician de los resultado positivos.

Desconocía su origen y eso que soy catalán.

Comment: Moltes gràcies. Claramente tengo que diversificar mi uso de Wikipedia en Inglés :)

Comment: Al respecto, también es interesante esta entrada de blog: http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-se-le-llama-esquirol-al-que-no-secunda-una-huelga/

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta no solo está en Wikipedia, sino también, en el diccionario de la RAE:

> [**esquirol**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=esquirol)
>
> (Del cat. esquirol, y este de L'Esquirol, localidad barcelonesa de donde procedían los obreros que, a fines del siglo XIX, ocuparon el puesto de trabajo de los de Manlleu durante una huelga).

Y por tanto, es *también* una palabra española. Y como tal, sea procedente del catalán, el francés, el portugués, el árabe,  el euskera o el quechua, puede sobrevivir perfectamente aquí.